# Why is azure database retrieving different records every time with same query?

Tags: sql, database, azure

I'm working with an azure database S1, I noticed some issues when I'm executing some queries. 
It is returning different results every time with the same query (I mean, a different number of records), I executed the query by hand with SQL Managment Studio, is the same with deleting.

This is the query that I'm running:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Trabajador] 
WHERE ClaveTipoNomina = '00156' 
AND ClavePeriodo = '2017-01-15';
```

Or:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Trabajador]  
WHERE ClaveTipoNomina = '00156' 
AND clavePeriodo = '2017-01-15';
```

If a run again the sentence again after few seconds it shows a different number of records.

The table is not complex:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trabajador](
[ClaveCompania] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[ClaveTipoNomina] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[ClaveTrabajador] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL,
[ClavePeriodo] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Linea] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Trabajador] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ClaveCompania] ASC,
[ClaveTipoNomina] ASC,
[ClaveTrabajador] ASC,
[ClavePeriodo] ASC,
[Linea] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

I already checked on azure panel about some special configuration for this database, but I coudn't find anything about this issue.

Could you tell why is happening that?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and describe those queries you mentioned?

Comment: Suspect Azure is behaving properly and someone is changing data

Comment: Thank You CPHPython, I already edited the question.

Comment: Someone else (or some other process) is adding or updating records in that table to match your conditions.

Comment: Without explicit ORDER BY clause the order of records is not determined nor predictable, depends on the way the DBMS accesses the data. Do you use any limiting? Did you check the whole result set or is it just looks different due to the order? Is there anything else (process, user, whatever) working with this table? Is/are those process(es) modifying data between two of your executions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a process or someone who is changing data in your database. This causes you to find new or other records each time you execute the query.